# Uwsgi disables django.request logging

Tags: django, uwsgi

If I start application using uwsgi I don't see logs related to django.requests.

But If I start the same code on the same machine using

```
manage.py runserver 8080
```

it works perfectly.

Any ideas why it might happen?

I run uwsgi by this command

```
/home/gs/python-env/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.d/uwsgi.ini --static-map /static=/home/gs/api/static/
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket=:8080
home=/home/gs/python-env
chdir=/home/gs/api
module=server.wsgi
env=server.settings
processes=1
enable-threads=true
```

My logging configuration from settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(process)d %(threadName)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/gs/api.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 16,  # 16Mb
        },
        'elasticsearch': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'api.common.elasticsearch_log_handler.ElasticSearchHandler',
            'hosts': [{'host': cluster.ES_HOST, 'port': 443}],
            'es_index_name': 'logstash',
            'es_additional_fields': {'type': 'api', 'cluser': cluster.CLUSTER_NAME},
            'auth_type': ElasticSearchHandler.AuthType.NO_AUTH,
            'use_ssl': True,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
       'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'elasticsearch', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'elasticsearch', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate':False
         }
    }
}
```

If I change info to debug for 'django' I will see my logs from django logger but not from django.request.

UPD: If I write my own middleware I can log requests. But I want to know why django.request doesn't work with uwsgi.

Comment: It should be `propagate`, not `propagade`. That may cause problems with handling all logs properly.

Comment: @GwynBleidD thank you for this correction. Though the main problem is not solved.. I also replicated it on another laptop

Comment: If you've changed code, change it also in your question. Also, try to change `'propagate': False` to `'propagate': True`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django's `runserver` provides the log messages that show up under `django.server`. When not running under `runserver` there are still some messages that can be logged to `django.request` (mostly error messages) but the informational log message for each request only exists in `runserver`. I verified this by looking at the uWSGI and the Django source.

If you want a similar log message you can use [django-request-logging](https://github.com/Rhumbix/django-request-logging).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I finally implemented my own logging middleware, which gave me even more flexibility,